Can I run xjc to generate classes with custom line endings?
I have a project which generates JAXB classes with XJC.
I use pycobertura which needs the sources of old and new version of the project.
The sources jar generated by the project contains all sources including the JAXB classes.
I have false positives with the line endings on the JAXB classes because the 2 builds to compare happened to run on different nodes, one on Linux, one on Windows. I want it to work regardless of which OS ran the build. Can I use a command line option for XJC to run with specific line endings ?
On Linux, I tried -Dline.separator=$'\r\n' but that generated only the carriage return. In Notepad++, I just saw CR as line break.
